# Signal handling doesn't work with -ansi or with POSIX define

Tags: c, linux, signals, ansi-c

I'm trying to use the signal function (I know it's deprecated and there are a lot of problems with its portability but I can't use sigaction).

I also need to compile with -ansi and -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L

If I compile with one of these flags, signal only works one time.
How can I get the same behavior with these flags without using sigaction please ?

```
    #include        <signal.h>
    #include        <stdio.h>

    static void     signal_handler(int nbr)
    {
      (void)nbr;
      puts("\nHi ! ");
    }

    int              main(void)
    {
      signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
      puts("Hi ! ");
      while (42);
      return (0);
    }
```

Be aware, the above code contains an infinite loop.

Thanks :)

Comment: Please edit your question to explain why you cannot use `sigaction`; you really should, and I can't see any reason to not use it!

Comment: I wasn't able because of my school's rules that asked us to use signal() syscall !

Comment: BTW, you cannot and should not use `puts` (since it is not an *async-signal-safe-function*) inside a signal hander. Read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From signal linux man:

```
       * On glibc 2 and later, if the _BSD_SOURCE feature test macro is not
         defined, then signal() provides System V semantics.  (The default
         implicit definition of _BSD_SOURCE is not provided if one invokes
         gcc(1) in one of its standard modes (-std=xxx or -ansi) or defines
         various other feature test macros such as _POSIX_SOURCE,
         _XOPEN_SOURCE, or _SVID_SOURCE; see feature_test_macros(7).)
```

I tried just at random and compiled with -D_BSD_SOURCE and on Ubuntu it works as intended.

Comment: Thank you ! It works really well ! When I saw it, I didn't thought it could help, I doesn't know System V semantics ! I will look into it :)
Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your system has the Unix/System V signal mechanism, which resets the signal action to SIG_DFL after the first signal.
So you have to reinstall the handler in the signal handler itself:

```
  static void     signal_handler(int nbr)
    {
      signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
      (void)nbr;
      puts("\nHi ! ");
    }
```

Comment: Not necessary, from linux signal man it follows that compiling with ansi enforces signal system-v -like behavior

Comment: @olegst That's what OP reports and that's why the OP observed that the signal handler is called only once?

Comment: It is, but strangely: on Linux the same program compiled with --ansi behaves differently depending on whether you use or do not use bsd_source flag as well

Comment: It's not strange at all. BSD implementation of signals doesn't reset the signal handler (using `-D_BSD_SOURCE`) while Unix & System V do reset. Obviously, using `sigaction` simply avoids this confusion (and other pitfalls with signal) but whatever reason OP says he can't use it.